# Python regex help, match anything before meet a letter

Tags: python, regex

Test Cases:

```
22 s    # 22
1.4 I   # 1.4
4.4.5 Apple    # 4.4.5
1993    # 1993
```

All i'm trying to get is everything  before [A-z] or [a-z]

Thanks

Comment: +1 on @boltclock's regex.  In the future, you might want to try and use a regex editor like http://pythex.org/ to help you experiment with and develop regexes.

Comment: line.split()[0] should be able to meet all your test cases ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
r'^[^a-zA-Z]+'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to not include trailing spaces, so matching "22 s" gives you "22" rather than "22 ":

```
>>> regex = r"^([^A-Za-z]+?)\s*(?:[A-Za-z]|$)"
>>> for input, expected in [
...   ("22 s", "22"),
...   ("1.4 I", "1.4"),
...   ("4.4.5 Apple", "4.4.5"),
...   ("1993", "1993"),
...   ("1993 ", "1993"),
...   ("1 2 3 a", "1 2 3"),
...   ("1 2 3 ", "1 2 3"),
... ]:
...   assert re.match(regex, input).group(1) == expected
...
>>> # no AssertionError means success
```

Or, you could match "^([^A-Za-z]+)" and rtrim afterward.